# Multiselect checkbox in Xamarin forms cross platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.forms

Below is the code I'm using for checkbox in Xamarin forms, but here I'm able to select only one item, I wanted to select multiple items from the checkbox. To the checkbox the data is bound from the database. Please help me.

Checkforms.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class Checkforms : ContentPage
    {
        private ObservableCollection<HelperModel> statusRecords;
        string[] statusList;
        public Checkforms()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetUserRoles();
          
        }
        public async void GetUserRoles()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
           var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://**********/api/Masters/getRoles");
            var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HelperModel>>(response);
            ListView1.ItemsSource = details;

           
        }
        private async void ListView1_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
            var statusData = e.SelectedItem as HelperModel;
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://********/api/Masters/getRoles");
            var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HelperModel>>(response);
            ListView1.ItemsSource = details;

          
            var item = details.Where(x => x.name == statusData.name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (item != null)
                item.IsSelected = !item.IsSelected;
           
        }
    }
```

Checkforms.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Checkbox_listview.Checkforms"
               xmlns:lv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.MultiSelectListView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.MultiSelectListView" Padding="0,20,0,0">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <ListView x:Name="ListView1" ItemSelected="ListView1_ItemSelected" lv:MultiSelect.Enable="true">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10  ">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                    <Image Source="select.png"  IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"
VerticalOptions="Center"  HeightRequest="40"
WidthRequest="40"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

HelperModel.cs

```
public class HelperModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private bool isSelected = false;
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
        //OnProperty changed method
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to select multiple items from the checkbox after binding it from the database, from here only one item is  selected at a time. Please help how to select multiple items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use `CollectionView` to replace the `listview` like following code. `CollectionView` have `SelectionMode`, you can set it to `Multiple`

```
  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <CollectionView  x:Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding StatusRecords}"   SelectionMode="Multiple"
                SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10  ">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                    <Image Source="select.png"  IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}" VerticalOptions="Center"  HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                          
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

        </StackLayout>
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

=========**Update**===============
Do you want to  Multiple pre-selection result?

If so, you should add the Property in your ViewModel. Note: No matter what is your model, please set the type of `ObservableCollection` to `object`

```
   ObservableCollection<object> selectedHelperModels;
        public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedHelperModels
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedHelperModels;
            }
            set
            {
                if (selectedHelperModels != value)
                {
                    selectedHelperModels = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHelperModels");
                }
            }
        }
```

Then If the `IsSelected` was selected to true. I will add it to the `SelectedHelperModels`.

```
  public MyHelperViewModel()
        {

           
            StatusRecords = new ObservableCollection<HelperModel>();
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected=false, name="test1" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = true, name = "test2" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = true, name = "test3" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = true, name = "test4" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = false, name = "test5" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = false, name = "test6" });

           
            SelectedHelperModels = new ObservableCollection<object>();


            foreach (var item in StatusRecords)
            {
                if (item.IsSelected)
                {
                    SelectedHelperModels.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

In the foreground xaml. Add the `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedHelperModels}"` in the `CollectionView`.

```
 <CollectionView  x:Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding StatusRecords}"   SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedHelperModels}" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10  ">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource imageToBool}}"  IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected} " VerticalOptions="Center"  HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                          
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

As you comment, you lack of the `ListView1_SelectionChanged` event. just add it in the layout background code.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        MyHelperViewModel myHelperViewModel;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myHelperViewModel=  new MyHelperViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = myHelperViewModel;
        }

        

        private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

=========**Update2**============

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, I found the `SelectionChanged` event cannot achieve it easliy, and it cannot meet the MVVM requirement, So I add a `TapGestureRecognizer` for `StackLayout` in the `CollectionView`.

Here is code.

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <CollectionView  x:Name="ListView1" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding StatusRecords}" 
                            
                            
                             SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedHelperModels}" 
                             SelectionMode="Multiple"
                            >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding  BindingContext.ChangeCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ListView1}}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                      />


                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource imageToBool},Mode=TwoWay}"  IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="Center"  HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Here is ViewModel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SelectMutiPlyDemo
{
    public class MyHelperViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<HelperModel> StatusRecords { get; set; }
        public ICommand ChangeCommand { protected set; get; }
        ObservableCollection<object> selectedHelperModels;
        public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedHelperModels
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedHelperModels;
            }
            set
            {
                if (selectedHelperModels != value)
                {
                    selectedHelperModels = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHelperModels");
                }
            }
        }
        public MyHelperViewModel()
        {

           
            StatusRecords = new ObservableCollection<HelperModel>();
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected=false, name="test1" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = true, name = "test2" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = true, name = "test3" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = true, name = "test4" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = false, name = "test5" });
            StatusRecords.Add(new HelperModel() { IsSelected = false, name = "test6" });
     
            SelectedHelperModels = new ObservableCollection<object>();

            foreach (var item in StatusRecords)
            {
                if (item.IsSelected)
                {
                    SelectedHelperModels.Add(item);
                }
            }

            ChangeCommand=new Command<HelperModel>((key) =>
            {
                if (SelectedHelperModels.Contains<object>(key))
                {
                    SelectedHelperModels.Remove(key);
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedHelperModels.Add(key);
                    
                }
                key.IsSelected = !key.IsSelected;


            });
        }
       
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: After replacing the listview to collection view I'm getting an error like:System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: Delete the `ViewCell` tab and  `ViewCell.View` tab in the `CollectionView`

Comment: In the `DataTemplate` tab, just use `<stacklayout>` directly. do not use `ViewCell` tab and `ViewCell.View` tab

Comment: code for SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged" is missing, please help me how to display the selected items. the select.png image is also not visible for selected items, after selecting the items i want to store it in DB.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read this article about the `SelectionChanged`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#multiple-selection

Comment: You should acheve the Multiple pre-selection as well.

Comment: @ Leon Lu Thanks for your reply, after referring to the given article I'm getting below error
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Please help,thanks in advance

Comment: Lu Sir, please help me,

Comment: Pre selection is not required, I want multiple selection and display of the same selected items , please help me , I've updated the code but I'm getting an error and not able to post here,Thanks

Comment: Sir please help in writing the code for ListView1_SelectionChanged,Thanks

Comment: @Mohammed Please see my update 2 in above answer, Is that your needs? If that is your needs, I will update my demo to you.

Comment: @Mohammed Are there any update for this issue? If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue